# Trying to get exact keys based on the given value in the nested object - Javascript (using recursion)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects, nested-object

I have an object with nested objects like:

```
let menu = {
    vegetarian: {
        vegStarter: {
            plainPizza: 100,
            cheesePizza: 200,
            onionPizza: 200
        },
    },
    nonVegetarian: {
        nonVegStarter: {
            meatLoversPizza: 160,
            chickenPizza: 200,
            chilliMeatPizza: 200
        },
        nonVegMainCourse: {
            seafoodPizza: 300,
            spinachEggPizza: 200,
            eggPizza: 250
        }
    }

};
```

I need to collect all keys that have the same value and I must use recursion. My value is 200. I tried the code with both **find()** and **filter()** methods but didn't get the desired result. Here's the code below with outputs:

```
function searchUsingPriceFromMainMenu(mainObject) {
    let arrOfKeys = [];
    Object.values(mainObject).forEach(val => {
        if (val === 200 && typeof val !== "object") {
            arrOfKeys = Object.keys(mainObject).filter(key => mainObject[key] === val);
            document.write(arrOfKeys + "<br>")
        } else {
            if (typeof val === "object") {
                searchUsingPriceFromMainMenu(val, arrOfKeys)
            }
        }
    });
}
searchUsingPriceFromMainMenu(menu);
```

With filter() method:

```
cheesePizza,onionPizza
cheesePizza,onionPizza
chickenPizza,chilliMeatPizza
chickenPizza,chilliMeatPizza
spinachEggPizza
```

With find() method:  **Just used find instead of filter. The code was same as above.**

```
cheesePizza
cheesePizza
chickenPizza
chickenPizza
spinachEggPizza
```

But I want result something like:

```
cheesePizza
onionPizza
chickenPizza
chilliMeatPizza
spinachEggPizza
```

So, am I missing something or is there any other way to get the same? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help =)

```js
const menu = {
  vegetarian: {
    vegStarter: {
      plainPizza: 100,
      cheesePizza: 200,
      onionPizza: 200
    },
  },
  nonVegetarian: {
    nonVegStarter: {
      meatLoversPizza: 160,
      chickenPizza: 200,
      chilliMeatPizza: 200
    },
    nonVegMainCourse: {
      seafoodPizza: 300,
      spinachEggPizza: 200,
      eggPizza: 250
    }
  }
};

const search = (obj, checkedValue) => {
  const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      return search(value, checkedValue);
    }
    if (value === checkedValue) {
      return key;
    }
    return [];
  });
  return result;
};

const searched = search(menu, 200);
console.log(searched);
```

Comment: Nice, if you remove the `return null` and change it to be `return [];`, you'll then be able to remove the additional filter

Comment: @NickParsons, sure, thank you =) i also like ur answer with extra parameter just to remove a magic number.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the entries of your object, and for each entry, check if it is a object. If it is, you can call your recursive function to process the child object. You can concatenate the result of this to the resulting array `res`, which is returned at the end of your function. Otherwise, if it is not an object, then you can check if the pizza value is equal to `200` (ie: val), and if it is, push it onto the result.

```js
const menu = {vegetarian: { vegStarter: { plainPizza: 100, cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200 }, }, nonVegetarian: { nonVegStarter: { meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200 }, nonVegMainCourse: { seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250 }}};

const getPizzasByValue = (menu, val) => {
  let res = [];
  Object.entries(menu).forEach(([pizza, pizzaVal]) => {
    if(Object(pizzaVal) === pizzaVal) { // check if value if object
      res = res.concat(getPizzasByValue(pizzaVal, val));
    } else if(pizzaVal === val) { // if value is not object, check if it matches the value
      res.push(pizza);
    }
  }); 
  return res;
}

console.log(getPizzasByValue(menu, 200));
```

Comment: Thank you @NickParsons. A little complicated for a beginner like me but understood in 4th attempt. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion.

```js
const menu = {vegetarian: { vegStarter: { plainPizza: 100, cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200 }, }, nonVegetarian: { nonVegStarter: { meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200 }, nonVegMainCourse: { seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250 }}};
function recurse(menuObj, val, arr) {
  for (let key in menuObj) {
    
    if (typeof menuObj[key] === "object") {
       recurse(menuObj[key], val, arr);
    } else if (menuObj[key] === val){
       arr.push(key)
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(recurse(menu, 200, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a generic function to filter the nested entries of an input object according to a predicate, and then write our menu function on top of that.  Here's one implementation:

```js
const filterEntries = (pred) => (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .flatMap ((entry) => [
    ... (pred (entry) ? [entry] : []),
    ... (typeof entry [1] == 'object' ? filterEntries (pred) (entry [1]) : [])
  ])


const matchingPrice = (price, menu) =>
  filterEntries (([k, v]) => v === price) (menu) 
    .map (([k, v]) => k)

const menu = {vegetarian: {vegStarter: {plainPizza: 100, cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200}}, nonVegetarian: {nonVegStarter: {meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200}, nonVegMainCourse: {seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250}}}

console .log (matchingPrice (200, menu))
```

The point is that JS objects can be considered a collection of key-value pairs.  So this object:

```js
{
  plainPizza: 100,
  cheesePizza: 200,
  onionPizza: 200
}
```

can be thought of as containing these key-value pairs:

```
[
  ['plainPizza', 100],
  ['cheesePizza', 200],
  ['onionPizza', 200]
}
```

and this one:

```js
{
  nonVegStarter: {
    meatLoversPizza: 160,
    chickenPizza: 200,
    chilliMeatPizza: 200
  },
  nonVegMainCourse: {
    seafoodPizza: 300,
    spinachEggPizza: 200,
    eggPizza: 250
  }
}
```

consists of these two key-value pairs:

```js
[
  ['nonVegStarter', {meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200}],
  ['nonVegMainCourse', {seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250}]
]
```

Using recursion to add all the nested children of our objects, we can find a list of all such key-value pairs in our object.  It might look like this:

```js
[
  ["vegetarian", {vegStarter: {cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200, plainPizza: 100}}],
  ["vegStarter", {cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200, plainPizza: 100}],
  ["plainPizza", 100],
  ["cheesePizza", 200],
  ["onionPizza", 200],
  ["nonVegetarian", {nonVegStarter: {meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200}, nonVegMainCourse: {seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250}}],
  ["nonVegStarter", {meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200}],
  ["meatLoversPizza", 160],
  ["chickenPizza", 200],
  ["chilliMeatPizza", 200],
  ["nonVegMainCourse", {seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250}],
  ["seafoodPizza", 300],
  ["spinachEggPizza", 200],
  ["eggPizza", 250]
]
```

Our `filterEntries` function does this and applies a predicate function (one which returns `true` or `false` for every value) to find all the entries in an object which match some condition.  It takes every entry of our object and creates a new array of entries.  If the predicate matches a given entry, that entry is included, and then, if the value at the entry is an object, we recursively call `filterEntries` with the same predicate and that value, including all matching results in the array.  It then combines the arrays for each entry into a single array, using `flatMap`.

We then use this in `matchingPrice`, creating a function which tests an entry to see if the value matches our given price, and passing that to `filterEntries` along with our menu object.  This creates an array of entries like this:

```js
[
  ["cheesePizza", 200],
  ["onionPizza", 200],
  ["chickenPizza", 200],
  ["chilliMeatPizza", 200],
  ["spinachEggPizza", 200]
]
```

and the final `map` call converts these into

```js
[
  "cheesePizza",
  "onionPizza",
  "chickenPizza",
  "chilliMeatPizza",
  "spinachEggPizza"
]
```

There is a good argument to write `filterEntries` slightly differently, layering the filtering on top of a separate utility function which generates all the entries as an array.  This wouldn't be too different:

```js
const allEntries = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .flatMap ((entry) => [
    entry,
    ... (typeof entry [1] == 'object' ? allEntries (entry [1]) : [])
  ])

const filterEntries = (pred) => (obj) =>
  allEntries (obj) .filter (pred)
```

This has the advantage of creating two helpful utility functions instead of just the one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the problem using JavaScript's generators. First we start with a function that generates all leafs of the tree, `t`, and yields only those which match the `price` input

```
function* matchingPrice (t, price)
{ for (const [k,v] of leafs(t))
    if (v == price)
      yield k
}
```

Now we write a `leafs` function which does a simple type analysis on the input, `t`, recurs on Objects, otherwise yields the input `key` and `t` as a pair -

```
function* leafs (t, key)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(t))
        yield* leafs(v, k)
      break
    default:
      yield [key ?? null, t]
  }
}
```

Put it all together in an executable snippet -

```js
function* matchingPrice (menu, price)
{ for (const [k,v] of leafs(menu))
    if (v == price)
      yield k
}

function* leafs (t, key)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(t))
        yield* leafs(v, k)
      break
    default:
      yield [key ?? null, t]
  }
}

const menu =
  {vegetarian: {vegStarter: {plainPizza: 100, cheesePizza: 200, onionPizza: 200}}, nonVegetarian: {nonVegStarter: {meatLoversPizza: 160, chickenPizza: 200, chilliMeatPizza: 200}, nonVegMainCourse: {seafoodPizza: 300, spinachEggPizza: 200, eggPizza: 250}}}

console.log(Array.from(matchingPrice(menu, 200)))
```

Output -

```json
[
  "cheesePizza",
  "onionPizza",
  "chickenPizza",
  "chilliMeatPizza",
  "spinachEggPizza"
]
```